# NinjaMyApp : Duplicate symbol

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am developing one application which is working fine but when i try to include NinjaMyApp folder (using drag & drop), I get duplicate symbol error.

```
ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_InfoView in /Users/xyzpath/NinjaMyApp-v0.32/NinjaMyApp-v0.32/4mnow-1.32/4mnowLaunchPad/4mnowLaunchPad.a(InfoView.o) and /Users/xyzpath/NinjaMyApp-v0.32/NinjaMyApp-v0.32/4mnow-1.32/4mnowBasic/4mnowBasic.a(InfoView.o) for architecture i386
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have an `InfoView` class in your application?

Comment: No. This is into .a file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about the static libraries you're using but apparently two of them have duplicate names for classes in them: LaunchPad.a and Basic.a.  Perhaps they're not meant to be used together?

Comment: Ummm....  If you don't need them both, remove one of them.  :-)  If you do need them both, check with the provider on how to use them together.

Comment: New error : ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_JKArray.objects in /Users/xyz/path/NinjaMyApp-v0.32/4mnow-1.32/4mnowMain/4mnowMain.a(JSONKit.o) and /Users/xyz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ZombieRide-cuszmggqbayxrzgjxqisjjynjawh/Build/Intermediates/xyzpath/Objects-normal/i386/JSONKit.o for architecture i386

Comment: So, now it sounds like JSONKit is being used both in a Main.a static library and directly in your own app. (Assuming that's "ZombieRide")

Answer (score 1):

don't #include or #import .m files. Just add those .m files into the Target | Build Phases.
Don't add .h files into build phases,
but #import .h files wherever you need those functions.

The compiler knows that it's just a header file "for information only" and that the bodies of the functions will be available when it will compile the .m files and put them all into 1 executable

Comment: How do you get "dont include or import" .m files from a linker error.

Comment: .o file mentioned in the error is your .m file.
You can also search your project for that duplicate symbol

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you include the class InfoView two time: Search in the project for the duplicate file and remove it. You can do it by searching the name in the project navigation search bars:

[image: Xcode project navigation search bar]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've imported InfoView.m instead of .h